# update the element at given index of an Array in Dotty(future Scala3)

Tags: scala, scala-3, dotty

In scala2:

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
arr(0) = 3
```

The updating operation works and arr turns to be:

```
arr = Array(3, 2, 3)
```

But in dotty:

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
arr(0) = 3
```

I found arr doesn't change

```
arr = Array(1, 2, 3) // didn't change
```

Further in dotty, when I try to update every element of an array by for expression:

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
for (i <- 0 until arr.length) arr(i) = 3
```

Magically, it changed:

```
arr = Array(3, 3, 3) // changed by for expression
```

I'm confusing why val array can't be updated in place while by for expression, it works.

Comment: In Dotty 0.24.0-RC1 it seems to be `Array(3, 2, 3)` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/41JuVEmTTIOZ1JwjmjRkXg

Comment: I tested also with Dotty 0.24.0-RC1 and both worked as expected. Maybe you would like an example? I have a repo with a Dotty project already set up that I can share if you would like to try it yourself.

Comment: There are issues with incremental compilation (as of now some of them are still unresolved), this could explain why the program doesn't change its behavior after compiling it for a second time.